# Unable to retrieve data from some table column - SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am working on SugarCRM accounts list view. I am trying to print some data from database, But nothing comes. Following is code:

```
$extra_action=$this->_tpl_vars['fields']['extra_time_adjust_c']['value'];
```

when I change `extra_time_adjust_c` to some column already exits in list view then it print those value, I think those array already configured in `_tpl_vars` I am searching `_tpl_vars` in smarty but unable to find.

How can i track back "_tpl_vars" and see how values are stored in this? Any alternative approach for this?

Comment: mention sugar version and view you are trying. It will be good if you share complete file path along with complete code.